# Change class active and input value on button click

Tags: jquery, button, onclick

I have two buttons with hidden inputs, what i want to do is to make them active onclick, when they become active i want the background color of the button to change and add the class active to button and change the hidden input value from 0 to 1, here what i have tried so far:

```js
$(".btn-default").click(function () {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
      $(this).toggleClass("active");

    });
```

```css
input{
display: none;
}

.btn-default{
background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 1</button>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1" value="0">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 2</button>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input2" value="0">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using jquery to apply the color, you can just apply it to your active class. And then use `.next().val()` to update the sibling input's value.

```js
$(".btn-default").click(function () {
   $(this).addClass("active").next('.form-control').val('1');
});
```

```css
input{
  display: none;
}
.btn-default{
  background: red
}
.active {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 1</button>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1" value="0">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 2</button>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="input2" value="0">
```

---

As a side note, you can probably use a `<input type="hidden" value="0">` instead of a text input. Then you wouldn't have to hide it manually with css.

Comment: thank you, but its okay to keep the active background color in the jquery because i have other active classes in my code and i don't want them to get mixed up, is it okay?

Comment: Yep, I was just making a suggestion based on the initial information. You can chain the original `.css()` you at the beginning and it will work the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to toggle active class and input value from 0 to 1  you can:

```js
$(".btn-default").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next(':input').val(function(idx, val) {
        return (+val == 0) ? 1 : 0;
    });
    console.log($(this).next(':input').val());
});
```

```css
input{
  display: none !important;
}

.btn-default{
  background-color: red
}
.active {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 1</button>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1" value="0">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 2</button>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="input2" value="0">
```